# Chart.js upgradation and compatibility with Angular versions

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm using angular 9 in my project and I have Chart.js v2.9.4 there I want to upgrade the Chart.js version to the latest I tried installing Chart.js latest versions but it seems not to be work my below chart only works on the Chart.js v2.9.4 ... my question is can i upgrade to the latest Chart.js and where I can see the compatibility versions list with Angular.

**bar-chart.component.html**

```
<div class="chart-container">
      <canvas  id="MyChart" >{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

**bar-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  public chart: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createChart();
  }

  createChart(){
  
    this.chart = new Chart("MyChart", {
      type: 'bar', //this denotes tha type of chart

      data: {// values on X-Axis
        labels: ['2022-05-10', '2022-05-11', '2022-05-12','2022-05-13',
                                 '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16','2022-05-17', ], 
           datasets: [
          {
            label: "Sales",
            data: ['467','576', '572', '79', '92',
                                 '574', '573', '576'],
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
          },
          {
            label: "Profit",
            data: ['542', '542', '536', '327', '17',
                                     '0.00', '538', '541'],
            backgroundColor: 'limegreen'
          }  
        ]
      },
      options: {
        aspectRatio:2.5
      }
      
    });
  }

}
```

I got this below error after I upgrade Charts.js can anyone help.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js 568:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (568:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     };
| class DatasetController {
>  static defaults = {};
|  static datasetElementType = null;
|  static dataElementType = null;
```

I wanted to know about Chart.js versions compatibility with Angular versions

Answer (score 0):

@ganesh-giri I believe you can use the latest Chart.js with the angular 9. As Chart.js is a different library and it's not related to Angular it's a generic Js/Ts library. However, If you are facing any error while using the updated version of the Chart.js